# GORM scanrows vs scan in a raw query

Tags: go, grails-orm, go-gorm

I found out I got different results using ScanRows or Scan.

if I use:

```
err=models.DB.ScanRows(nodes, &node)
```

I get empty values in some fields.

If I replace the structure node for all the attributes:

```
err = nodes.Scan(&node.NodoId, &node.NodoIdPadre, &node.TipoNodo, &node.SubFormulaId, &node.FuncionId, &node.TipoTerminoId, &node.TerminoId,&node.FuncionDesc,  &node.CodFormula, &node.TipoTerminoDesc, &node.DescTipoNodo, &node.OperadorId, &node.Operador )
```

It does not have any NULL value, I replace these Null values with coalesce function.

[image]

This is node struct

```golang
type Node struct {
    NodoId          int
    NodoIdPadre     int
    TipoNodo        int
    SubFormulaId    int
    FuncionId       int
    TipoTerminoId   int
    TerminoId       int
    FuncionDesc     string
    CodFormula      int
    TipoTerminoDesc string
    DescTipoNodo    string
    OperadorId      int
    Operador        string
}
```

Thank you.

PD: Very difficult to past code in this editor, I got a lot of identation error.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: *"Very difficult to past code in this editor"* -- Do not use the extra indentation to render code, instead use triple-backquotes to demarcate the code section. And you can also explicitly specify the programming language of the code. See the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75201336/revisions) (click on the "Side-by-side Markdown" tab).

Comment: As I wrote, ScanRows does not work fine.